# Strange uv problem

Tags: modeling, uv

I am having a problem trying to texture my character his uv seems to be shaped strangely and I don't know how to make the texture work with it because of this

[image: this is what it looks like]

this is what it looks like

Comment: Try to triangulate the mesh with ctrl+t and then unwrap again.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: Face on the background with diagonal line means some faces of the mesh weren't unwrapped (or their UV coordinates were reset). Several others pentagons are probably connected only with one vertex; you might want to reset UV map and unwrap again; or at least post some screenshots of the model.

Comment: I don't understand why triangulate mesh? It does not give me sense. He need mark seams (or mark it correctly) or use smart UV project. I my opinion triangulate mesh = more trouble than help in this case. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Smart Uv Project option when you press U to unwrap.

[image]

Just leave the default settings and press "Ok"

[image]

That should help with the unwrapping, although it will probably not give you the exact results you need.  For that, there are plenty of great tutorials you could watch.  Here is one you could start with:  [Character Unwrapping Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W-ZmDKuB6HI)